# How to move embedded key-value pair one level up in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have an embedded document within a document as following :

```
{
user:"Alex",
actions: {
            openFav:8,
            clickShare:5
         }
}
```

So what i need is to move the embedded document `actions` one level up and have them in different collection (so i could do a quick stats report).

So the end result will look like this :

```
{
user:"Alex", 
openFav:8,
clickShare:5 
}
```

how could i do this in mongodb javascript shell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the properties using a `for...in` loop, then delete `actions`:

```
var o = { user: "Alex", actions: { openFav: 8, clickShare: 5 } }
for (var k in o.actions) { o[k] = o.actions[k] }
delete o.actions
```